# Java Generic Type Converted to Scala does not accept super class itself

Tags: java, scala, types, existential-type, bounded-wildcard

I'm writing a framework. The interfaces are written and compiled in Java code. The client uses Scala and those interfaces. Here is an example of the interface.

```
public interface Context {
   MyComponent<? extends File> getComponent();
}
```

Now my scala code uses the interface as follows.

```
val component = context.getComponent();
println(calculate(component));

def calculate( component: MyComponent[File] ): Unit = ???
```

Scala compiler is throwing errors at line 2 for `println(calculate(component))`. The error is: Type mismatched, expected: MyComponent[File], actual: MyComponent[_ <: File].

Comment: That's because `? extends File` corresponds to the existential type `_ <: File` in Scala. So, what happens if you replace `def calculate( component: MyComponent[File] ): Unit = ???` by `def calculate(component: MyComponentFile[_ <: File]): Unit = ???`, as the error message suggests?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: you are right. Thanks man. Just got back to Scala after long time. Really didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's wildcard type

```
? extends File
```

corresponds to the existential type

```
_ <: File
```

in Scala. Try changing the signature

```
def calculate(component: MyComponent[File]): Unit = ???
```

to

```
def calculate(component: MyComponent[_ <: File]): Unit = ???
```

Also note that if `MyComponent` were a Scala-class that is under your control, then changing the invariant type parameter to covariant type parameter `+F` might also work, because then every `MyComponent[F] forSome { type F <: File }` would be a special case of `MyComponent[File]`.